# How to create independent sections, which consits of menu and more pages automatically

Tags: routes, 7

I have little problem with creating independent sections on the web.

I have content type named project. It is basically landing page, which has own menu and this menu can link multiple simple pages. These projects have simillar structure, on every on them is page like timeline, news & events... Now when I want to create new project, I need to create new project, than create multiple simple pages, create menu, add menu to this project and so on. It is really complicated. Is there any way how can this be automatized?

Example: I will create new project, and menu and simple pages will be created automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try with field collection module and divide groups of fields in sections as explained in field collection module documentation. You will get what you want!